# Custom HeaderFooterView Bad Access

Tags: ios, objective-c

In the following code, `viewForHeaderInSection` last line, I am getting `EXC_BAD ACCESS` error.

**ViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    movies = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
           (NSArray*)[[Section alloc ] init:@"Z" movieNames:@[@"M", @"S"] isExpanded:false],
           (NSArray*)[[Section alloc ] init:@"M" movieNames:@[@"Y", @"A"] isExpanded:false],
           (NSArray*)[[Section alloc ] init:@"H" movieNames:@[@"M", @"F"] isExpanded:false], nil
           ];
}

-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    ExpandableHeaderFoorterView* headerView = [[ExpandableHeaderFoorterView alloc] customInit:((Section*)movies[section]).genre withSection:section withDelegate:self];
    // BAD ACCESS
    return headerView;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text =  ((Section*)movies[indexPath.section]).movies[indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

**ExpandableHeaderFoorterView.m**

```
- (id)customInit:(NSString*)title withSection: (NSInteger) section withDelegate :(id<ExpandableHeaderFooterViewDelegate>)delegate
{
    self.textLabel.text = title;
    self.headerSection = section;
    self.headerDelegate = delegate;
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your implementation of your custom init method is all wrong. That's not how you write an initializer in Objective-C. Also, since it is an initializer, the name should start with `init...`.

Since you are extending `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` you need to call the proper super initializer.

```
- (id)init:(NSString*)title withSection:(NSInteger)section withDelegate:(id<ExpandableHeaderFooterViewDelegate>)delegate {
    self = [super initWithReuseIdentifier:@"SomeUsefulIdentifier"];
    if (self) {
        self.textLabel.text = title;
        self.headerSection = section;
        self.headerDelegate = delegate;
    }

    return self;
}
```

Comment: What is wrong by having the following `@interface ExpandableHeaderFoorterView : UITableViewHeaderFooterView` ?

Comment: I have come to know that if  I use `self =[ super init]`; then custom init method should start with `init`; therefore, your solution is right if I change the method name from `customInit` to `initCustom` and keep `@interface ExpandableHeaderFoorterView : UITableViewHeaderFooterView` as it is. Thanks a lot for providing answer, appreciated!

Comment: I can't believe I overlooked the problem with the name of the method. Yes, it should start with `init...`. I've also updated the answer to reflect that you are extending `UITableViewHeaderFooterView`. You need to call the proper super initializer.

Comment: Thanks a lot again @rmaddy